# Poisson process of even-numbered arrivals?

Tags: stochastic-processes, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

Let $N(t)$ be a Poisson process of rate $\lambda$, and $N'(t)$ be a process in which we count only even-numbered arrivals; that is, arrivals 2,4,6... of the Process $N(t)$. Is $N'(t)$ a Poisson process? Hint: sum of independent exponential random variables follows 'Erlang' distribution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $0$ is an even number, right?

Comment: @i70707: yes, I think it including 0 arrivals.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are discarding $1,3,5, \ldots$ 'th arrivals and only taking $0, 2, 4,\ldots$'th arrivals. Then the $2$nd arrival from the old process is considered as the $1$st arrival in the new process. The $2$nd arrival time from the old process is the independent sum of exponential random variables, thus it is [Erlang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlang_distribution) 's distribution. The independent sum of exponential pdf can be done by using [convolution](https://www.dartmouth.edu/~chance/teaching_aids/books_articles/probability_book/Chapter7.pdf) or by using the [moment generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function).